# Not able to use cache properly in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following code snippet in my angular js web application. Intention is to use cache in controller to make the app faster.

I have defined the following cache factory in my services.js file which is to be utilized by several controllers in my app:

```
appServices.factory('AppCache', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory){
        return $cacheFactory('app-cache');
}]);
```

Now I have the following code in one of my controllers:

```
appControllers.controller('pageController', ['$scope', 'AppCache', 'AnotherService', 
    function pageController($scope, AppCache, AnotherService) {

        $scope.init = function () {

            if (angular.isUndefined(AppCache.get('d')))
            {

                AnotherService.get({},
                        function success(successResponse) {
                            $scope.data = successResponse.response.r;
                            AppCache.put('d', $scope.data);
                        },
                        function error(errorResponse) {
                            console.log("Error:" + JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
                        }
                );
            }
            else
                $scope.data = AppCache.get('d');
}
}
```

The problem is I am not able to save or retrieve any data in / from the cache. My page becomes blank when I use the above code as no data is retrieved.

Please help me understand my mistake.

Comment: what is the variable `d`? Do you mean this to be a string `'d'`? Also is any error logged in your browser console?

Comment: Yes it is string 'd'. But still I see my app is hitting database for getting the result rather than taking it from angular cache.

Answer (score 0):

You named your cache `'app-cache'`, and you try to access it by `'d'`. In the controller, just replace the `'d'` with `'app-cache'`, it should work:

```
appControllers.controller('pageController', ['$scope', 'AppCache', 'AnotherService', 
    function pageController($scope, AppCache, AnotherService) {

        $scope.init = function () {

            if (angular.isUndefined(AppCache.get('app-cache')))
            {

                AnotherService.get({},
                        function success(successResponse) {
                            $scope.data = successResponse.response.r;
                            AppCache.put('app-cache', $scope.data);
                        },
                        function error(errorResponse) {
                            console.log("Error:" + JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
                        }
                );
            }
            else
                $scope.data = AppCache.get('app-cache');
            }
```